# Adding A LOT Attributes to Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

I am implementing a login system, which require to collect a lot of user data, for example:

college, course, graduate year, start year, hobby, .... about 20-30 of them.

Is it wise to put them all into Devise? Or create another Model to handle that?

Comment: Can you mark one of the answer as correct? if you are satisfied with the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good idea to put so much of data in devise model. Devise model record is always fetched from database for every request.(You can see it from logs)

You can add it in another model and add association.
e.g. you can add profile model
Assuming you have User model as devise model.
You have to take care of creating profile record after either User creation or User logs in first time or as per your requirement.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one   :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to   :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user_info model with this association, in user.rb

```
has_one :user_info
```

On, sign_in it should create an instance of user_info if its not present in the databse
This approach would be better if you want to add 20-30 columns